# Nvidia GTS 450 HDMI problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi

**Problem:**

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTS 450 video card and a Samsung TV Series 4 43 and I have it connected to my computer via a Mini HDMI cable and all the hardware works perfectly.

I installed 12.04 64bit perfectly, but the problem is when I want to change the screen resolution. I tried to change the driver installed that comes directly from the Nvidia page but it gave me an error at the end. Maximum resolution it presents is 1024x 768 and it is supposed to introduce more resolutions now that it is connected through a HDMI cable.

**Question:**

Is there an updated driver I can get for linux which would work? If not does anyone have a suggested fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The best way to install the Nvidia driver is through jockey.  It is in your settings under "Additional Drivers"  You can also type "jockey" in your dock to pull up the Additional Drivers.

Once you have it installed you can type "nv" into your dock and that should pull up the Nvidia Settings Manager.  Once you set this up you can go into the displays and set the Resolutions in there.

The default Ubuntu display manager won't work correctly.

You can install them with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Let me know if this helps.

To have the settings remain after reboots you need to run the Nvidia settings as root and save the xorg file.

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

After you make all the changes you want click the "Save X Configuration File" and save it to the default location.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I did that and I still can see a higher resolution to 1024x768 and presumably with HDMI cable should have access to higher resolutions. :(

Comment: I added a screenshot.  Are you telling me in this tool you don't see additional resolutions?

Comment: Yes thank you very much for the screenshot, change the resolution achieved but when I reboot present an error saying that the selected resolution was not allowed. And with that mistake in almost the entire screen could not do anything I could not see the menus or icons or anything. :'(

Comment: Check my edits to see if that helps.

Comment: Hello! Is there a way to install the latest driver from Nvidia that appears on the website of Nvidia in Ubuntu???? As I read you can but only with commands. I intenado what it says on the page but says Nvidia modify a course file called "X" but not how. :(

Comment: There is a way to install it using the x-swat ppa, but honestly I tried them and didn't have any difference in performance.  It is just a couple of command line parameters once you google x-swat nvidia driver.  Good luck.  I prefer the offical Ubuntu packages over PPAs since it is tried and true.