# Dual Screens not working nVidia

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, gnome-classic

I just install Ubuntu to my P.C. I started it up with both my screens plugged into my nVidia's dvi and vga ports and logged in, change the skin to classic gnome, because that's how it was when I last used Ubuntu (8.1), and both screens were working separately.

The trouble is that I got a notification saying there was nVidia drivers to be installed, so I install them and restart my P.C., and when I get back on only one of my screens is working and when I go into Displays (All Settings, Displays) it doesn't register my other screen at all. It calls my working screen "Laptop".

I've tried looking through several pages of Google but I see no answer. I did try to find the nvidia-settings to see if that had the answers but sadly I couldn't locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a post about this over here [Nvidia GTS 450 HDMI problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184516/nvidia-gts-450-hdmi-problem/184520#184520)

But basically you need to use the Nvidia settings control panel not the default ubuntu control panel.

You also need to run it as root and then save the x configuration file.

It is pretty simple to do and I have it setup this way on my laptop with a RGB connector and it boots up and pops up from suspend perfectly so there is hope.

I am not sure how the old Gnome works with it since I use Unity, but I assume it is the same.

Comment: Hey, @Goddard thanks for the help, but when I config the X Server Display Configuration to how I want it and press "Save to X Configuration File" it gives me this error "Failed to parse existing X config file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'!"

Comment: Thats because you need to run it as root.  Try sudo nvidia-settings.  I list all the details in my other post.